# R POSIXct origin weird behavior

Tags: r, date, posix

I have a problem with `as.POSIXct()`. I need to process a lot of data and in order to minimize memory used for dates I want to change `origin`. So, I use:

```
as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-05-15 00:00:01",origin=("2015-05-15 00:00:00")))
```

and get 1431637201 when I thought I should get 1. The questions is how to handle origin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `origin` parameter is not suitable for this purprose.

Try

```
as.integer(as.POSIXct("2015-05-15 00:00:01") - as.POSIXct("2015-05-15 00:00:00"))
#[1] 1
```

or

```
as.integer(difftime("2015-05-15 00:00:01", "2015-05-15 00:00:00"))
```

The `origin` parameter is used to convert a number to a date / date-time object. The number represents units of time (in seconds) passed since an "epoch". The standard epoch for the POSIX* class in R is "1970-01-01". Other systems use other default origins. When using numbers that represent date/time objects that originate from other systems (like SAS or Excel), the "origin" needs to be changed from the "usual" "1970-01-01" and adapted according to the definition of the source from which the numbers have been supplied in order to reproduce the correct date/time in R.

The "origin" option is ignored if a date instead of a number is supplied as the first parameter.

The number obtained in the example shown in the OP depends on the timezone, and it can be reproduced in this case like this:

```
as.POSIXct(1431637201, origin="1970-01-01", tz="CEST-3")
#[1] "2015-05-15 00:00:01 CEST"
```

See `?as.POSIXct` and `?base::as.Date` for more information and examples concerning the use of `origin`.

Comment: wasn't sure how you wanted to include seconds. put in parantheses

Comment: Thank you, @PierreLafortune

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using large numbers like `1431637201` and still use POSIXct format?

Comment: @Andrew Since those numbers represent seconds after a certain point in time (the epoch), the numbers are almost inevitably large. One possibility to deal with smaller numbers consists in subtracting an offset that corresponds to a date/date-time that one can define as the starting point, like `my.start <- as.integer(as.POSIXct("2016-06-01 00:01:00")); as.integer(as.POSIXct("2016-06-07 00:01:00") - my.start)`. This is similar to the suggestions posted above, with `difftime()` being probably one of the easiest options. Hope this helps.